# How to take a snapshot from UIImage of a UIImageView that is scaleAspectFit mode?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an image in a `UIImageView`:

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit        
imageView.backgroundColor = .red
```

because of `.scaleAspectFit` the image view has some red borders and thats OK:

[image: imageView with .scaleAspectFit image]

User can added some `UIView` like label or images over the `imageView`.
In final step I used the following code to save edited image and user can share it or save it to photo library:

```
private func generateImage() -> UIImage? {
    var finalImage: UIImage?
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: imageView.frame.size.width, height: imageView.frame.size.height), true, 0)
    imageView.drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.frame.size.width, height: imageView.frame.size.height), afterScreenUpdates: true)
    finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

The problem is that the `finalImage` still has the red borders from `imageView`.

Comment: Why are you not simply querying `imageView.image`? Do you need the image resized to your image view's size?

Comment: @DarkDust, What you mean? use imageView.image.size as drawHierarchy CGRect?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. You have an image view displaying and image, and it seems you want to save the image in that image view (but without the red borders). Is that correct? If so, why are not simply saving the image in `imageView.image`?

Comment: @DarkDust, correct. because the user can add some `UILabel` and another `UIImageView` over the ImageView. So final image is mixing of some image and labels over the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `CGRect` of the `UIImage` displayed in the `UIImageView` in `AspectFit` content mode. Please create extension of `UIImageView` like this,

```
extension UIImageView {
    var contentClippingRect: CGRect {
        guard let image = image else { return bounds }
        guard contentMode == .scaleAspectFit else { return bounds }
        guard image.size.width > 0 && image.size.height > 0 else { return bounds }

        let scale: CGFloat
        if image.size.width > image.size.height {
            scale = bounds.width / image.size.width
        } else {
            scale = bounds.height / image.size.height
        }

        let size = CGSize(width: image.size.width * scale, height: image.size.height * scale)
        let x = (bounds.width - size.width) / 2.0
        let y = (bounds.height - size.height) / 2.0

        return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    }
}
```

You can now use `imageView.contentClippingRect` to read how read the position and size of the image inside.

You have to do minor changes in your method, call your function with appropriate bounds as `contentClippingRect`.

Let me know in case of any queries.

**UPDATE**

Please try this [UIImageView+Extension](https://gist.github.com/justin/4979919), this might help you. It is in Objective-C code, convert it in Swift.

You can try this as well,

```
    let image  = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Cat03")
    let x: CGRect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: image.size, insideRect: imageView1.frame)
    print(x)
```

Above code gives you size perfectly.

Comment: I tried this extension that I get from hackingwithswift.com but not helped.

Comment: Please give me some time, will do it

Comment: By `AVMakeRect` I founded the image size and handle the rest of issues. Thanks.

Comment: misfit Origin position